# Improving Linq queries with multiple Include() / ThenInclude()

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning Linq queries, and some people told me every time I do a `FirstOrDefault()` or a `ToList()` for example, a request to the database will be made. So I was trying to do a Linq with multiple includes in a Person DbSet, like this:

```
DbSet.Include(x => x.ManyToManyProperty)
     .ThenInclude(x => x.Company)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

But what I wanted was only active companies, but to do that before the `FirstOrDefault()` (so I don't bring stuff I don't need from the database) I did a `Select`, so the code went like this:

```
DbSet.Include(x => x.ManyToManyProperty)
     .ThenInclude(x => x.Company)
     .Select(x => new Person
          {
               ManyToManyProperty = x.ManyToManyProperty
                   .Where(c => c.Company.Active)
                        .Select(c => new ManyToManyProperty
                        {
                             Company = c.Company
                        }).ToList()
           }
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

So the problem is with the above code, I do a `ToList()` on the `ManyToMany` property and then `FirstOrDefault()` on the `Person` DbSet, this will make this Linq go to the database 2 times, affecting performance, and I could not find a way to get all the info I wanted with only a `FirstOrDefault()`.

Anybody could me give me an idea how to do this? Also if any suggestion for code improvement will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that query above indeed produces 2 calls to database? Or is it your assumption? If you do select to different model, then generally you don't even need to specify `Include` calls, as EF will generate correct joins and select only data that you actually specified, applying all filters that you added (i.e. `c.Company.Active`)

Comment: multiple people told me everytime i make the IQueryable "concrete" by transforming with a ToList() or a FirstOrDefault() for example a call to the database is made, if anybody knows a way to check if this is really happening i would appreciate that info too ^^

Comment: Try your luck with [`Global Query Filters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

Answer (score -2):

Its generally not a good idea to use Include, primarily because the cons outweigh the pros.
You might end up pulling more data from the DB than you need, and the performance of Include is dependent on the number of rows in all the tables that are included (performance will be directly proportional to the product of all the tables' number of rows).

Its a better Idea to use joins so that you end up getting exactly what you want. Also read up about Lazy loading vs eager loading. That should give you a better picture.

If you want to use data from one query in another, dont give it a `.ToList()`. If you use just the query, its in an IQueryable form and can be used as a table itself (use it for joins, group bys, anything you want. It basically translates to a SELECT query, which can be used on other places).

This query would help

```
var result = 
from ds in DbSet
join mtmp in ManyToManyProperty on ds.Property1 equals mtmp.Property1
join cmp in Company on mtmp.Property2 equals cmp.Property2
join p in Person on cmp.Property3 equals p.Property3
where p.IsActive //taking company as Active if it has active Persons
select cmp;
```

This query will give you all the companies which have active persons. This may or may not be a single company, so FirstOrDefault isnt applicable here as the query might have 0 to N entries whereas FirstOrDefault is applicable for 0 to 1 entries.

Ps. This will hit the database only once.

**EDIT 1:** 
After reading the comments and reviewing the code, here is a query which most probably will work:

```
var result = (from mtmp in db.ManyToManyProperty
             join cmp in db.Company on mtmp.Company equals cmp.Id
             join p in db.Person in cmp.Id equals p.CompanyId
             where cmp.IsActive
             select p).ToList(); 
// This needs ToList because there can be many companies which are active.
```

Comment: Don't confuse EF "Include" with some sort of full join. Include works through joins internally and simply eagerly loads navigation properties data from their tables. And in most cases this results in speedup because all data is fetched in single db round-trip.

Comment: It is sped up In most cases yes, but not always, especially in this scenario. The question is regarding increasing performance, and Include doesnt always give the best results. Many bigger companies advise against using it too.
The 2 trips can be saved if we use joins. The server will send the query to the database after it evaluates what the LINQ translates to. When you have that, the query will get everything you need in one shot, in a single query.

Comment: Please read more about `Include` - it works exactly using joins under the hood. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: I checked it out, thanks for the link :). Yeah, but how is it useful for the question's scenario? The OP needs a condition and 3 levels of relations, and after all that, he is selecting the `ManyToManyProperty` object just with `Company`. Its much better if we go with joins here.

Comment: He doesn't need explicit join or include for this scenario. EF will manage it just by parsing select expression.

Comment: hi guys thanks for the answer, i improved the query a little bit, i noticed in this case i don't really need the includes, i can do it all with the Select.
My problem is i can't find a way to hit the database only once and filter the ManyToManyProperty, if i go like:
ManyToManyProperty. = x.ManyToManyProperty
.Where(x => x.Company.Active) 
this part is still an IQueryable, and when i finish the query with a FirstOrDefault() the ManyToManyProperty will be null.

Comment: sorry for the lack of tags on the above code, first time doing it i will format it in 5 minutes lol

Comment: Hey @yuribsl, try using the query I wrote and let me know the performance.

Comment: @yuribsl check the edit I just made. It should help solve your question. (I have taken the scenario where `Company` has `IsActive` field in the database. If you want the company `isActive` flag to come from the `person`, join the person table with company, give the condition in the where clause and give the iQueryable a `.Distinct()` before the `.ToList()`)

Comment: so, i used SQL Server Profiler to trace my calls to the database, and i made 1 LINQ with a FirstOrDefault only and another with a FirstOrDefault and a ToList, the SQL Server Profiler gave 2 calls for what i could understand, so now i'm not sure if a ToList and a FirstOrDefault will do more calls than normal, here is the print of the 2 requests: http://prntscr.com/nsesz3 - @Yura please check the screenshot

Comment: Sorry, but this is all wrong. In the first place because the desired result is a list of Persons and both of your queries return companies. Secondly, *if* you want to return companies, don't join with `ManyToManyProperty` which duplicates them. Thirdly, don't join *anyway* if there are navigation properties. Fourthly, `Include` can indeed be a very good idea. *Too many* includes can be detrimental, sure, but it's never the product of rows in the individual tables. You didn't understand the question. OP is asking for filtered `Include` --as many people keep doing-- which isn't supported.

Comment: Isn't supported? Really? Well i actually did it with the above example and when testing with SQL Server Profiler it gave me 2 calls to the database same as if i did only 1 ToList() or FirstOrDefault() ( screenshot  above has the example ).
So if i'm not missing something the above example worked? lol

Comment: @yuribsl That's not the same as filtered `Include`, it's a work-around and about the only thing you can do. BTW, the `Include`s in your query don't do anything and can be removed without essentially changing the query (see [ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes)).

Comment: @GertArnold made the changes to take Person. Thanks for the info though, learnt a lot from this thread despite it not being my question :D